# Efficient Way to find count of value in list within an upper and lower bound

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, data-structures

Given a large unordered list with duplicates, how do I find the the count of values in the list that lie between the lower and upper bound, inclusive with a good time and space complexity? Will be great if there's an explanation in python. Looking for a O(nlog(n)) approach

```
Sample input
5 # number of elements in unordered list
2 4 98 3 100 # unordered list. values in list from 1 to 10 ^7
4 # number of subsequent bounds as input
99 101 # left is lower bound right is upper bound
1 5
100 100
2 2

Sample output
1 # 1 number in list between 99 and 101 inclusive
3 # 3 numbers in list between 1 and 5 inclusive
1
1
```

Comment: Sort the list and use binary search.

Comment: should I use merge sort to sort the list? as for binary search how can it be done to implement count for lower and upper bounds

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this is what you are looking for but in order to find the count, in a interval of a list you could do something similar to the following:

```
list[start:stop].count(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in python

- Merged sort the list
- Used binary search (bisect library)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).